# SQL - Avg value by year

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, average

```
create table sales(
  invoiceid int primary key,
  deptid int, 
  salesamt decimal(10,2),
  salesdate datetime
  );
  
insert into sales values (101, 2, 2111.02, '20160102');
insert into sales values (102, 2, 421.00, '20160202');
insert into sales values (103, 2, 675.00, '20160202');
insert into sales values (104, 2, 4355.00, '20160302');
insert into sales values (105, 2, 975.00, '20160304');
insert into sales values (106, 2, 1021.00, '20160402');
insert into sales values (107, 2, 2106.00, '20160425');
insert into sales values (108, 2, 2799.81, '20160501');
insert into sales values (109, 2, 4335.75, '20160502');
insert into sales values (110, 2, 12006.00, '20160521');
insert into sales values (111, 2, 5220.00, '20160602');
insert into sales values (112, 2, 7198.02, '20160618');
insert into sales values (113, 2, 4795.00, '20160625');
insert into sales values (114, 2, 5341.00, '20160706');
insert into sales values (115, 2, 5795.00, '20160718');
insert into sales values (116, 2, 6400.00, '20160725');
insert into sales values (117, 2, 14795.00, '20160812');
insert into sales values (118, 2, 43395.00, '20160825');
insert into sales values (119, 2, 47595.00, '20160914');
insert into sales values (120, 2, 46795.00, '20160930');
insert into sales values (121, 2, 6223.00, '20161010');
insert into sales values (122, 2, 7702.00, '20161012');
insert into sales values (123, 2, 11292.00, '20161107');
insert into sales values (124, 2, 33211.00, '20161126');
insert into sales values (125, 2, 16430.00, '20161206');
insert into sales values (126, 2, 87010.00, '20161221');
insert into sales values (127, 2, 2111.02, '20170102');
insert into sales values (128, 2, 421.00, '20170202');
insert into sales values (129, 2, 675.00, '20170202');
insert into sales values (130, 2, 4355.00, '20170302');
insert into sales values (131, 2, 975.00, '20170304');
insert into sales values (132, 2, 1021.00, '20170402');
insert into sales values (133, 2, 2106.00, '20170425');
insert into sales values (134, 2, 2799.81, '20170501');
insert into sales values (135, 2, 4335.75, '20170502');
insert into sales values (136, 2, 12006.00, '20170521');
insert into sales values (137, 2, 5220.00, '20170602');
insert into sales values (138, 2, 7198.02, '20170618');
insert into sales values (139, 2, 4795.00, '20170625');
insert into sales values (140, 2, 5341.00, '20170706');
insert into sales values (141, 2, 7004.00, '20170718');
insert into sales values (142, 2, 14991.00, '20170725');
insert into sales values (143, 2, 34076.00, '20170812');
insert into sales values (144, 2, 47950.00, '20170825');
insert into sales values (145, 2, 40795.00, '20170914');
insert into sales values (146, 2, 41795.00, '20170930');
insert into sales values (147, 2, 47295.00, '20171010');
insert into sales values (148, 2, 47395.00, '20171012');
insert into sales values (149, 2, 41795.00, '20171107');
insert into sales values (150, 2, 47895.00, '20161126');
insert into sales values (151, 2, 87666.00, '20161206');
insert into sales values (152, 2, 9401.00, '20161221');
```

For the above data I am trying to determine the average sales considering only year. For example the data as only 2 years, so the average is total/2. One way of doing is may get distinct years & total sum from subquery and then average. I am exploring if there is a better way of doing it. Any pointers are helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am now trying to get monthly average sales for the above data ( which is total sales/24  (2 years - 24 months)). Using the SQL below either I get month count as 12 (distinct) or 52 which is the total record count. How can I determine the  Avg sales considering 24 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select year(salesdate) salesyear, avg(salesamt) avg_sales
from sales
group by year(salesdate)
order by salesyear
```

This produces one row per year, with the average value of `salesamt`.

On the other hand, if you want the average of yearly sales, then you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select avg(salesamt) yearly_avg_sales
from (select sum(salesamt) salesamt from sales group by year(salesdate)) t
```

I think the query you had in mind was:

```
select sum(salesamt) / count(distinct year(salesdate)) yearly_avg_sales
from sales
```

It produces the same result as the second query. You would need to test both queries against your data to see which performs better.

Comment: I want only one row for whole data instead of row per year.

Comment: @gvs: I was speculating on this. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, @GMB. This is what i am looking at. You are right, second query is in my mind....

Answer (score 0):

select year(salesdate) as yearofsales , avg(salesamt) as  salesavg from sales group by year(salesdate) order by yearofsales